# PHP returning array with requirements done

Tags: php, arrays

I have a few functions here and im struggeling to get the right output.

the main idea is to use function called `buildinginfo` and  call function `avaliableBuildingBuildings` to loop trough `buildinginfo` `s arrays and loop trough requirements to find out if the requirements is complete or not.

in my database, my `main_building` level is 1.

every other table, is empty.

when calling `avaliableBuildingBuildings` i get the output under this line, that would list buildings i can create.  you can see that the requirements for main_building are 3, then the barracks shouldnt be created.

**q: how can i fix my code so it would acually just give me the array of buildings i can build?**

current output:

```
array(5) {
  ["barracks"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["max"]=>
    int(1)
    ["requirements"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["main_building"]=>
      int(3)
      ["rally_point"]=>
      int(1)
    }
  }
  ["blacksmith"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["max"]=>
    int(1)
    ["requirements"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["main_building"]=>
      int(3)
      ["academy"]=>
      int(3)
      ["barracks"]=>
      int(3)
    }
  }
  ["embassy"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["max"]=>
    int(1)
    ["requirements"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["main_building"]=>
      int(1)
    }
  }
  ["marketplace"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["max"]=>
    int(1)
    ["requirements"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["warehouse"]=>
      int(1)
      ["granary"]=>
      int(1)
      ["main_building"]=>
      int(3)
    }
  }
  ["palace"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["max"]=>
    int(1)
    ["requirements"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["main_building"]=>
      int(5)
      ["embassy"]=>
      int(1)
      ["residence"]=>
      int(0)
    }
  }
}
```

full code:

```
 function isBuilt($villageid,$name) {
        $buildinginfo = $this->buildinginfo();
        $thisBuilding = $buildinginfo[$name];

        $built = $this->CI->db->query("SELECT * from `$name` where `villageid`='$villageid'")->row();
        return ($built ? $built : false);
    }

    function requirementsDone($villageid,$name) {
        $buildinginfo = $this->buildinginfo()[$name];
        $canbebuilt = true;
        if (isset($buildinginfo['requirements'])) {
            $requirements = $buildinginfo['requirements'];


            foreach ($requirements as $reqname => $level) {
                $building = $this->isBuilt($villageid, $reqname);
                if ($building) {
                    echo "needs that $reqname (".$building->level.")is higher than $level to build $name <br><br>";
                    if ($building->level >= $level) {
                        echo "<br> $reqname is acually higher ! <br><br>";

                    } else {
                        echo " i cant acually build this.. <br><br>";
                        $canbebuilt = false;
                        break;
                    }
                } else {
                    $canbebuilt = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if ($canbebuilt) {
            echo "result to build $name is true<br>";

        } else {
            echo "result to build $name is false<br>";

        }
        return $canbebuilt;
    }

    function existingBuildings($villageid) {

        $buildinginfo = $this->buildinginfo();
        $buildings = array();
        foreach($buildinginfo as $name => $array) {
            $built = $this->isBuilt($villageid,$name);
            if ($built) {
                $buildings[$name] =   $built;
            }

        }

        return $buildings;

    }

    function avaliableBuildingBuildings($villageid) {
        $avaliable = $this->avaliableBuildings($villageid);

        $tobuild = array();
        foreach($avaliable as $name => $built) {

            if (isset($built['requirements'])) {
                $req = $built['requirements'];

                foreach ($req as $reqname => $level) {
                    $canbuild = $this->requirementsDone($villageid, $reqname);

                    if ($canbuild) {
                        echo "verify to build $reqname is true <br><br>";
                                                   $tobuild[$name] = $avaliable[$name];

                    } else {
                        echo "verify to build $reqname is false <br><br>";

                        break;
                    }
                }
            } else {

            }
        }
        return $tobuild;
    }

    function avaliableBuildings($villageid) {
        $buildinginfo = $this->buildinginfo();

        foreach($this->existingBuildings($villageid) as $name => $built) {
            if (array_key_exists($name,$buildinginfo)) {
                unset($buildinginfo[$name]);
                echo "removing $name <br>";
            }
        }

        return $buildinginfo;



    }

    function buildinginfo() {

        $info = array(
                'academy' => array('max' => 1),

                'barracks' => array('max' => 1,
                    'requirements' => array(
                        'main_building' => 3,
                        'rally_point' => 1,
                    )
                ),
                'main_building' => array('max' => 1,
                    'requirements' => array(
                        'main_building' => 1,
                    )
                ),
                'greatbarracks' => array('max' => 1),
                'greatstable' => array('max' => 1),
                'heromansion' => array('max' => 1),
                'rally_point' => array('max' => 1),
                'stable' => array('max' => 1,'requirements' => array(
                    'blacksmith' => 3,
                    'academy' => 5,
                )
                ),
                'blacksmith' => array('max' => 1,'requirements' => array(
                    'main_building' => 3,
                    'academy' => 3,
                    'barracks' => 3,
                )
                ),
                'forge' => array('max' => 1),
                'tournament_square' => array('max' => 1),
                'trapper' => array('max' => 1),
                'cranny' => array('max' => 1),
                'embassy' => array('max' => 1,
                    'requirements' => array(
                        'main_building' => 1
                    )
                ),
                'marketplace' => array('max' => 1,'requirements' => array(
                    'warehouse' => 1,
                    'granary' => 1,
                    'main_building' => 3
                )
                ),

                'palace' => array('max' => 1,
                    'requirements' => array(
                        'main_building' => 5,
                        'embassy' => 1,
                        'residence' => 0
                    )
                ),
                'residence' => array('max' => 1),
                'town_hall' => array('max' => 1),
                'trade_office' => array('max' => 1),
                 'treasury'  => array('max' => 1),
                'granary' => array('max' => 99, 'new' => 20),
                'warehouse' => array('max' => 99, 'new' => 20)

        );

        return $info;
```

}

Comment: This reminds me of Warcraft TFT :)

Comment: @Vucko  oh? How come

Comment: Barracks, blacksmith, rally point :D good old days. (who am I kidding, I still play).

Comment: Hehe . Im soon done with my code, just have this problem left @Vucko

Comment: You have a table for each building type, like one table for barracks, other for blacksmith... Or what you getting here: ``$built = $this->CI->db->query("SELECT * from `$name` where `villageid`='$villageid'")->row();``

Comment: @Cristo  that is correct . One for each building type. Containing level, Id and villageid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're requirements check loop is doubled. That resulted in checking if any of the required buildings can be build (and it always can since there's no nested requirements). Just get rid of inner loop and it should be fine.

```
function avaliableBuildingBuildings($villageid) {
    $avaliable = $this->avaliableBuildings($villageid);

    $tobuild = array();
    foreach ($avaliable as $name => $built) {
        if (isset($built['requirements'])) {
            if ($this->requirementsDone($villageid, $name)) {
                echo "verify to build $name is true <br><br>";
                $tobuild[$name] = $avaliable[$name];
            } else {
                echo "verify to build $name is false <br><br>";
            }
        } else {

        }
    }
    return $tobuild;
}
```

Ps. Those "echoes" don't help, do they?:) Think about TDD - this process resolves more issues than just logic errors (it would force you to introduce fake data layer for example -> decoupled code)

Comment: I will check this first thing on Monday.  But out of the code , so do it also check the requirements of each of the requirements is built / have required level etc ?

Comment: Yes. For example when checking `barracks` - you've tried to build 'main_building` (again) which met requirements so it returned true - one true result was enough to add 'barracks' into avalable buildings. The right logic `all or false` was in nested loop (but that loop operated on wrong dataset).